# "Falling back on PROMPT mode since _cordovaNative is missing" error in older Android SDK versions

Tags: android, cordova, android-2.2-froyo

I am Developing an `Android` Application using `Cordova-2.2.0, Android sdk` I'm using is `4.1` and my application working Fine.

when I tried to test this Application on `Android 2.2` and `2.3.3` I'm getting some log indicating  like below and and my application page is not opening.

LOG is:

```
01-02 15:42:08.166: D/CordovaLog(486): Falling back on PROMPT mode since _cordovaNative is missing.
01-02 15:42:08.166: D/CordovaLog(486): file:///android_asset/www/js/ext/cordova-2.2.0.js: Line 1032 : Falling back on PROMPT mode since _cordovaNative is missing.
01-02 15:42:08.166: I/Web Console(486): Falling back on PROMPT mode since _cordovaNative is missing. at file:///android_asset/www/js/ext/cordova-2.2.0.js:1032
```

I don't know why it is appearing and how to solve it.

Answer (score 10):

There is nothing to fix. When the PhoneGap framework detects that you are running on a version of Android that does not support the regular way of passing information between the Java and JavaScript code it reverts back to the safer PROMPT mode.

Comment: how can I remove the alert prompts? and the Web Console keeps on logging this one

07-30 13:46:32.124: I/Web Console(2879): processMessage failed: invalid message: at file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:977

Answer (score 0):

seems a problem with the connection to your native code or proof Android project in Eclipse project clean and recompile to see what happens, or be sure to put the libs folder in your project with the corresponding. jar PhoneGap

@dagavi90

Answer (score -5):

Add this to your manifest:

```
    <supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
```

Comment: Besides this not being a useful answer, it encourages lazy use of permissions. E.g., There's no need require camera permission if your app does not actually take photos.